# Theon method of extracting square roots

Tags: math-history

I am confused about a certain sentence in the book The works of Archimedes where a method of extracting a square root by Ptolemy is explained. I will write here only the last step because the sentence I am confused with concerns its context.

> We have then to subtract $$2(67 + {4\over60}){55\over60^2} + ({55\over60^2})^2,$$ or $$ {442640\over60^3} + {3025\over60^4}$$
>   from the remainder ${7424\over60^2}$ above found. 
>   The subtraction of ${442640\over60^3}$ from ${7424\over60^2}$ gives ${2800\over60^3}$, or ${46\over60^2} + {40\over60^3}$; but Theon does not go further to subtract the remaining ${3025\over60^4}$, instead of which he merely remarks that the square of ${55\over60^2}$ approximates to ${46\over60^2} + {40\over60^3}$.
>   As a matter of fact, if we deduct the ${3025\over60^4}$ from ${2800\over60^3}$, so as to obtain a correct remainder, it is found to be ${164975\over60^4}$.

I am mostly confused about the sentence where he says that the square of ${55\over60^2}$ approximates to ${46\over60^2} + {40\over60^3}$. This is not really a correct approximation so I want to know if maybe something else is meant by this sentence. Also if someone could explain what is the reason of rewriting a fraction as a sum of two fractions?

Comment: The rewriting is easy. This is [sexagesimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexagesimal) form of numbers.

Comment: What about the approximation?

Comment: Well it **is** an approximation isn't it?

Comment: Well, not really. Try calculating the two numbers, they are not really close.

Comment: Yes, well we are using Babylonian sexagesimal floating point,and in that case they **are** close neglecting powers of $60$. Wikpedia states: "Because there was no symbol for zero it is not always immediately obvious how a number should be interpreted, and its true value must sometimes have been determined by its context"

Comment: $$\frac {2800}{60^3} = 0.01\overline{296}$$ and $$\frac{164975}{60^4} = 0.01272955\overline{246913580}$$ How is that a poor approximation? They differ by less than $2\%$. (And FYI - note how I rewrote each of the fractions as a sum of fractions with powers of $10$ in the denominators - this is a trick we still use today, but with $10$ instead of $60$.)

Comment: These are not the two numbers being approximated. He says the square of ${55\over60^2}$ approximates to ${46\over60^2} + {40\over60^3}$

Comment: Somos can you elaborate on your last comment? In which sense they are close?

Answer (score 1):

It is my best understanding that when Theon says the square of $\frac{55}{60^2}$ approximates to $\frac{46}{60^2}+\frac{40}{60^3}$, that he means they are both small enough numbers that he finds it fine to treat their difference as zero, so this works as a fine spot to end the calculation.

As you point out, it’s really not a great approximation relative to the size of the numbers, but it’s not relative to their size that Theon means, it’s relative to the size of the number he’s trying to extract the square root of.